# Where is the transmission-daemon torrent list stored?

Tags: transmission

I don't remember sleepwalking, but this morning I found `transmission-daemon` uninstalled. I've reinstalled it, but when I open it up through the web interface or `transgui`, there are no torrents listed. I assume I've lost them, but just in case, where is this data supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This data is stored in `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info` (requires root access to view, use `sudo` from the command line or install `nautilus-gksu`).

<sub>In my case depressingly empty.</sub>

Comment: Any idea on how to change this default dir? just by looking at transmission's [configuration options](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles) I can't find out if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

They are under:

```
/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/transmission-daemon/torrents
```